# Drupal local import shows default website

Tags: installation, drupal, xampp, drupal-8, development-environment

I have been given a Drupal project and I am trying to set it up to run locally.

I'm using XAMPP to host the project.

I had several pitfalls while trying to set it up. Now I've reached a point where I can see a drupal project, although not the one I've been given.

So now I'm asking for help on how I can run the project drupal code instead of some default that is being shown. I've added setting files as required by the installer. But now it's not running the drupal project that I want.

How can I get the project code to run?
How does drupal find the code that is shown?
[Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lcdB.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Seems like there was an issue with the database reference in settings.php. From now it's loading the correct website!